# 3x3 user input bingo game

Tags: c#, matrix

I wrote a code for a 3x3 bingo game. It check for line, bingo or nothing for a given input where I get a 3x3 bingo card and next 15 numbers extracted.
Basically I use a 2D user inputed array for the 3x3 bingo card, then I have a function which asks me to input 15 numbers. If all the numbers from the 3x3 bingo card are present in those 15 extracted numbers then I have "bingo". If I have numbers from a line but not all numbers then the program will output "line". And if i will not have bingo neither line the program will output "nothing".
Here is the input:

- 1 2 3
- 90 91 92
- 93 94 95
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7
- 8
- 10
- 11
- 12
- 13
- 14
- 15
- 16

The program should return "line" but instead I get "nothing"

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        const int numberOfRows = 3;
        const int numberOfColumnns = 3;
        const int numbersExtracted = 15;
        int[,] bingoCard = ReadBingoCard(numberOfRows, numberOfColumnns);
        int[] numbers = ReadNumbersExtracted(numbersExtracted);
        PrintResult(bingoCard, numbers);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static int[,] ReadBingoCard(int rowsNumber, int columnNumber)
    {
        int[,] card = new int[rowsNumber, columnNumber];

        for (int i = 0; i < rowsNumber; i++)
        {
            string[] array = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

            for (int j = 0; j < columnNumber; j++)
            {
                card[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(array[j]);
            }
        }

        return card;
    }

    static int[] ReadNumbersExtracted(int numbersExtracted)
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[numbersExtracted];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbersExtracted; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        return numbers;
    }

    static bool CheckForBingo(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbers)
    {
        int numMatchesFound = 0;
        foreach (var number in bingoCard)
        {
            for (int numIndex = 0; numIndex < numbers.Length; numIndex++)
            {
                if (number == numbers[numIndex])
                {
                    numMatchesFound++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return numMatchesFound == bingoCard.Length;
    }

    static bool CheckForLine(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbers)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < bingoCard.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            int colMatchesInRow = 0;

            for (int col = 0; col < bingoCard.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                if (Index(bingoCard, row, col, numbers, ref colMatchesInRow))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                break;
            }

            if (colMatchesInRow == bingoCard.GetLength(1))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    static bool Index(int[,] bingoCard, int row, int col, int[] numbers, ref int colMatchesInRow)
    {
                for (int numIndex = 0; numIndex < numbers.Length; numIndex++)
                {
                    if (bingoCard[row, col] != numbers[numIndex])
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    colMatchesInRow++;
                    break;
                }

                return colMatchesInRow == bingoCard.GetLength(1);
    }

    static void PrintResult(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbersExtracted)
    {
        if (CheckForBingo(bingoCard, numbersExtracted))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("bingo");
        }
        else if (CheckForLine(bingoCard, numbersExtracted))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("line");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("nothing");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking if one line has matched numbers is the same as checking for bingo (all input numbers) but for one row only.

Try to implement the function `CheckForLine()` this way :

```
static bool CheckForLine(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbers)
{
    int numMatchesFound = 0;
    foreach (var number in bingoCard)
    {
        for (int numIndex = 0; numIndex < numbers.Length; numIndex++)
        {
            if (number == numbers[numIndex])
            {
                numMatchesFound++;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (numMatchesFound == bingoCard.GetLength(1))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The 2 bingo-card cases below will work :

```
1 97 99
90 2 92
93 94 3
```

and

```
1 2 3
90 91 92
93 94 95
```

Comment: Thank you. Instead it would not work if I got nothing. It will display line instead of nothing.

Comment: Only if i have horizontal line should display "line". Not for columns and diagonals.